# Sony VAIO SVT1311 brightness change doesn't works

Tags: brightness, sony

I bought the new ultrabook Sony VAIO SVT1311. Many things work but brightness control doesn't. I see the splash bubble (that reacts to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) but the brightness doesn't change. It stays permanent at 100% and I can't do anything with it.
The graphics card is integrated Intel HD3000.

Comment: what is output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`

Comment: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness doesn't change on Sony laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186002/brightness-doesnt-change-on-sony-laptop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get working brightness key. try following

execute `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change this line

`GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to something like below

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot . See if brightness keys are working.

It is still possible ubuntu won't remember your brightness settings. So you have to change brightness each time.

Please let us know the result as many sony users are facing this problem.

---

Update: This is for setting brightness manually.

Try following for both path shown by `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly. Most probably the intel one should work.

Get the maximum brightness:

`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`

Try a lower value to set the brightness, say output is 2048 so I will try with half of it

`echo 1024| sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

**If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

```
echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
exit 0
```

I have another question. Does your system has hybrid graphics card? whats the output of `lspci | grep vga` ?

Also you can try with [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool]

Comment: I changed grub settings: now the bubble can switch between 90% and 100%, but anyway the brightness remains maximum. This notebook hasn't light sensor so the way under the link is not for me.

Comment: I have updated. Please try them.

Comment: Yes, it works! Only with intel (max - 4882). With /sys/class/backlight/sony/brightness (max - 7) it doesn't. If I set value to rc.local, this will be for all session and coldn't be changed during work.

Comment: I have only HD3000 without another graphics card

Comment: yea.. update `rc.local`. And accept this answer by clicking the tick button on upper left of my answer

Comment: Is there a way to write this control method to udev rules? I bought this notebook for my wife and I think she'll didn't like to use the Terminal to change brightness. ;-)

Comment: I am not that much expert.. :(

Answer (score 0):

adding **acpi_backlight=vendor** to the grub command line like suggested above did not help in my case. My workaround was to use the **intel_backlight** command from command line.

example:

```
# set the brightness down to 20%:
intel_backlight 20
```