# Unable to change brightness on a Toshiba L750

Tags: 12.04, xorg, brightness, toshiba-satellite

So, as a number of users seem to be experiencing, I am unable to change brightness on my laptop. Using the Brightness and Lock in settings, the slider moves but brightness does not adjust. The fn keys work for volume but not for brightness. I have updated my drivers and installed all updates, however the brightness is still at maximum.

I have heard that opening `sudo gedit /etc/x11/xorg.conf` and entering `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` can fix this, however when opening xorg.conf through Terminal I am greeted with a blank document... Not very reassuring.

Toshiba L750 Laptop

Nvidia Graphics Card

Dual boot with Windows

Comment: its `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` .. capital `X`. Also please post result of `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` . Is your system optimus enabled. what is output of `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: For `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` I get:

`/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
`/sys/class/backlight/toshiba/brightness`

Unsure how to tell if Optimus enabled, as for `lspci | grep VGA` I get:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0dec (rev a1)`

Comment: Please try the steps over here.. http://askubuntu.com/a/154562/35775 . Just adjust the paths accordingly. Let me know the result.

Comment: Hi, I updated grub and rebooted however the brightness did not adjust. For both `echo 1024| sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/toshiba/brightness` and `echo 1024| sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` I am met with **Invalid Argument**

Comment: you need to get the max brightness first. Please recheck

Comment: Apologies, maximum brightness returned **7** for both `acpi_video0` and `toshiba`. As such I tried `echo 4`, again, for both `acpi_video0` and `toshiba`, brightness did not change.

Comment: sorry can't help in such case. I out of options. :(

Comment: Please try tools mentioned here http://askubuntu.com/questions/56155/how-can-i-change-brightness-through-terminal

Comment: Not an issue, thanks for your help nonetheless, seems to be rather odd. I just use Windows when on battery as an alternative.

Comment: Hi. I think this is a similar question without a solution. Kindly try the solution metioned here. I don't expect it to work, but try anyhow: http://askubuntu.com/a/153077

Comment: Hi, I want to thank everyone for the above suggestions however upon fiddling with the xorg.conf file, finally I am able to change brightness by entering `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`. I don't know why this didn't work the first time I tried it, but now it works. My eyes are thankful haha

Comment: I have the same issue with my Toshiba L755 laptop. Raymond could you post your xorg.conf? It would give some clues on how to fix the situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on Sony Vaio VPCEH and Ubuntu 12.04. The fn Keys moving the brightness slider but not affecting the real brightness on screen.

I edited `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (very simple file) and added the line:

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

I rebooted the machine and now it works! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I myself have an L750 too and tried everything to resolve this issue and didn't succeed. But after weeks of googling i ran into this solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11543948&postcount=40

Take a look at this reference which doesn't exactly match your laptop but the issue is the same.

What I did is almost the same as it's written in the linked post. Only thing you should notice is that Ubuntu 12.04 has the 3.4.1 version of gnome settings daemon, however I still downloaded the 3.2.2 source because the method of the detection of your display is changed in 3.4.1 so you can't modify it as you should.

After installing the latest package of nvidiabl, applying the changes to gsd-backlight-helper.c, compiling it, copying it into the right folder and adding nvidiabl to /etc/modules brightness controll works for me.

Of course you have to switch "toshiba" with "nvidia_backlight" and not "sony".

Not sure if this will work for you though, because my graphics card isn't an optimus one.

I hope i could help.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate all the help with this **but**, after changing the xorg.conf a few times (and fortunately _not_ breaking my computer as a result) my computer finally allows me to change brightness. My eyes are very thankful and I appreciate the help of the community (:

Comment: @RaymondStanden You can select this solution as the correct solution so people can benefit from this in the future

Answer (score 0):

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro L870 and the xorg.conf solution did not work for me. However, I remembered that in Ubuntu 8.04 it was possible to program what special actions the keys did. Well, here's how you can do this in Ubuntu 12.04:

1. First install *xdotool*.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Open *System Settings* (Applications->System Tools->System Settings in Gnome).
3. Open *Keyboard* and go to the *Shortcut* tab.
4. Click the "+" button at the bottom of the page and add the following shortcut:

   ```
   Name: Brightness Down
   Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
   ```

   Click "Apply".
5. On the *Shortcut* tab click on the word "Disabled" to the right of the "Brightness Down" entry. Now press the key that should decrease the brightness on your keyboard - this was *F2* for me but it may be *F6* or even something else on your keyboard.
6. Click the "+" button again and add the following entry:

   ```
   Name: Brightness Up
   Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
   ```

   Click "Apply".
7. On the *Shortcut* tab click on the word "Disabled" to the right of the "Brightness Up" entry. Now press the key that should increase the brightness - *F3* for me but possibly *F7* or even something else on your keyboard.

Now sit back and enjoy the brighness, or darkness depending on which key you press.

Answer (score 0):

I used Toshiba L735 with nvidia. I also have problem about brightness won't change. following these step can solve this problem.

1.open terminal
2.enter : sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
3.entering Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
4.I rebooted the machine and now it works! Thanks to all!

and these not working. you might also do these step below too.

1.install NVDIA 319 post-releases
2.go to terminal and type “sudo apt-get install xbacklight”
3.restart
4.go to terminal and type “xbacklight = 50”

Answer (score 0):

I have Toshiba Satalitte L750. The solution that worked for me and also solved other graphical problem is to change to NVIDIA driver from "Additional drivers"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pilot6 This clearly is an attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

it is iöprotant where you have add enablebrightness controll

it must ne in the 
**section "device"**

endsection
[ubuntu 14.04 fn brightness nvidia not working samsung r540](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558980/ubuntu-14-04-fn-brightness-nvidia-not-working-samsung-r540)