# Brightness doesn't change on Sony laptop

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, brightness, vaio, sony

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop for first time and every thing work well but the only thing doesn't work is the **brightness** doesn't change when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> with <kbd>Fn</kbd>

So I can't adjust the Brightness and sometimes I need to decrease it for more time working on battery

and the **bubble** appear that it changed but nothing happens

My laptop is Sony VAIO series F with NVIDIA GEFORCE ...

and **NVADIA accelerated graphic driver** is activated

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/162421/35775)

Comment: i tried that but nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LCD Brightness Control**

Once you have installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers as suggested above, you may notice that your brightness control keys do not work properly. This is fixable by editing one's xorg.conf file. Open a terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Append a line so it appears like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You will need to restart your graphical server (or reboot) for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If installing all updates and rebooting does not work, try installing [`nvidiabl`](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/),

> a little Linux driver [...] that enables the control of laptop backlight connected to NVIDIA chip using the `/sys/class/backlight` interface.

It worked for me on an HP Elitebook 8570w.

Comment: @Eng.amr19 Click on the link and scroll down... the README page is right there!

Comment: i can't understand it ... please just give me the instruction

Comment: @Eng.amr19 Download the latest version of the ``.deb`` package from the [download section](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/downloads) and install it using your package manager (dpkg, synaptic, Software Center, Gdebi, QApt Package installer, ...). It's like any other ``.deb`` package installation.

Comment: i tried that but it is the same no changes 
i still can't change the brightness