# Lenovo Y400 ubuntu 12.04 can't change brightness

Tags: 12.04, brightness, lenovo, function-keys

The ubuntu seems to be always on the max brightness.

I cannot change the brightness. Really strange.

What I have tried:

1 Install the latest Nvidia Driver    does not work

2 change x

`sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "Device"
Identifier    "Default Device"
Driver    "nvidia"
Option    "NoLogo"    "True"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

This would make the <kbd>fn+</kbd> key successfully change the value of `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` and `actual_brightness`

However the brightness will still stay the maximum.

Comment: Nvidia based device apparently. Could you try `nvidiabl` as described in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/186767/88802)? It doesn't work for all machines, but you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Finally I found a method to solve it by using xrandr in [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1907928&page=5)  (but the *fn + up/down*  still cannot be used).

1. First get the output name entering the code below in terminal: 
   `xrandr -q | grep " connected"` 
   Then I get the result:
   `LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm`

   My output name is  **LVDS-0**.
2. Then try to change brightness: (use your output name)
   `xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 0.8`
   Then the brightness of my laptop becomes 80%.
   Hope this will help you.